# Set URL-Scheme for Windows.UWP app in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, url, xamarin.forms

I want to access my windows uwp app on windows with a URL-Scheme, like [ spotify:// ] 
I got it working on android by placing 
`IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, DataScheme = "myapp", Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable })` 
in MainActivity.cs, but I cant get it to work on windows.

How do you select the URL-Scheme for an xamarin forms uwp app?

Comment: UWP do this in another way. You could refer to the article (https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/) and MS docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps

The main problem I had was that I taught you must have :// in the end, but that didn't launch the app, In actuality, you must end the url Scheme with just ":". ( myapplication: works, but  myapplication:// only works on android)